# Can I apply a WP theme to a specific custom page template?

Tags: themes, templates, pages, customization

One section of my website is going to be completely different visually than the rest of the pages, is there a way to apply a WP Theme to specific page templates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there is, using `template_redirect`, which you would put in the functions.php file - Here's what I use:

```
function uniquename_default_template() {
    if(get_post_type() == 'posttype') : /* You could use is_single() instead of get_post_type() == '' or any type of conditional tag) */
    include(TEMPLATEDIR . 'path/to/theme/file.php'); /* You could use TEMPLATEDIR to get a file from a template folder, or PLUGINDIR to get a file from the plugins directory - doesn't support HTTP requests */
    exit; endif;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'uniquename_default_template');
```

The above code checks for a `post_type` called `posttype`, if it is, it will include the PHP file specified in the include statement by redirecting the template using the `template_redirect` function.

Comment: Ok so I put this function into the functions.php of my main theme. Then I have a second theme that I want to apply only to a specific page template. I can test this condition on the first line of your function with `if(is_page_template('template_special_area.php') )`. Then I have to include this said template, how do I do that? Doesn't TEMPLATEDIR point to the main theme fodler?

Comment: @mike23 - that's just example code, jared suggested to have some template inside a plugin but you can naturally use some template from within another theme and then use TEMPLATEDIR to point to the right file.

Comment: @mike23 - hakre is right, you would need to use `TEMPLATEDIR` (which points to `/public_html/wp-content/themes/`) if the file is in your themes folder. But my code may be a little buggy, I haven't tested it much but it might just work for what you need. Either way, the function you're looking for to use is `template_redirect` - I wouldn't count on my code above to work 100%.

Comment: @mike23 - I revised my code a bit, it is in the proper format now and above is how it should be used.